# How to take input from user using prompt window in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I take login credentials during runtime using prompt window in Selenium webdriver like we use prompt and echo commands in selenium IDE?

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Which login are you automating? Ideally automation should not require manual intervention.

Comment: Automation will not have any human intervention, the whole point of automation is lost if there is any human intervention.

Comment: Baap ko mat sikha...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a console input you can try to use the following code (assuming you are using java ). Ideally automation will not have any human intervention

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = bufferRead.readLine();
```

Hope this helps you.